# Anchor peers in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was going through hyper ledger documentation and came across a type of peer known as anchor peer. After searching a lot I was not able to find suitable explanation regarding them. Some say that they are used to find all peers of a member of the channel. What does it mean and what anchor peer actually are?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you have several organizations in the channel, i.e Org1, Org2, Org3.
They need to find each other in order to talk to each other.
Even if you have 100 peers in each organization, you don't need to give all the peers the endpoints of all the other peers - it's enough that the peers would know some peer(s) in the channel, and once a peer learns of another peer's endpoint and can successfully communicate with it - it also learns about all the peers that the other peer already knows.

The anchor peers are just that - endpoints that represent peers (for each organization, there are its own set of anchor peers) that their endpoints are not expected to change, and once peers join to the channel and get a config update about the anchor peer(s), they can contact the anchor peers and exchange information about the peers they know (they tell the anchor peer about it) and obtain from the anchor peer information about the peers the anchor peer knows.

Comment: This leads to a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970262/peer-discovery-in-multiple-org-network

Comment: Answered :) 
Feel free to ask me in DM on rocket chat if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused about the difference between `Anchor peer` and `Leader peer`,so that's the answer:

`Anchor peer`:

It’s a peer node on a channel that all other peers can discover and communicate with. Therefore, every participating organization in a channel has an anchor peer. Peers belonging to an organization can query this peer to discover all peers belonging to other organizations in the channel.

`Leader peer`：

When an ordering service node must send a block to the peers in the channel, it sends the block to each of the leading peer associated with the organizations. The leading peer in turn distributes this block to other peers belonging to the same organization.