# Peer discovery in multiple Org network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We are setting up a multi-Org network, and have Anchor Peers defined and installed. We understand that Anchor Peers are used in peer discovery, but one question remains open: When a client needs to collect endorsements, how does it discover peers in the other Org to direct proposals to for endorsement? Is the Anchor Peer a "directory service" (and if so, how do we read the directory from the client SDK), or is it a "gateway" (and if so, how do we say how many endoresments we are trying to gather)?

Answer (score 4):

> When a client needs to collect endorsements, how does it discover
>   peers in the other Org to direct proposals to for endorsement?

Excellent question. There is a [document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-overview.html) for that.
Pasting below the relevant part:

*The service runs on peers – not on the application – and uses the network metadata information maintained by the gossip communication layer to find out which peers are online. It also fetches information, such as any relevant endorsement policies, from the peer’s state database.
With service discovery, applications no longer need to specify which peers they need endorsements from. The SDK can simply send a query to the discovery service asking which peers are needed given a channel and a chaincode ID.*

In a nutshell, starting from Fabric v1.2, the SDK can query a peer for the peers it needs to request endorsements from.

> Is the Anchor Peer a "directory service"

No, it is not. The idea is that starting from Fabric v1.2, every peer that you trust as a client (i.e - a peer that belongs to your own organization) can serve your SDK as a discovery service endpoint.

There is also a brand new (friendly to use!) [CLI tool](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-cli.html) that is included in v1.2 and can be used to query the discovery service on a peer.

There should be documentation published for the various SDKs once v1.2 is released.

> or is it a "gateway" (and if so, how do we say how many endoresments
>   we are trying to gather)?

It is also not a gateway, it's only used for peers to bootstrap their membership view when they startup or join a channel.